# Python Package Modules Installing Error in PyCharm

Tags: module, pycharm, windows-10, python-3.7

Good day everyone,
To run my code i needed to set up my dependencies (I'm using PyCharm as IDE), while most of the packages were installed without any problems, there are 2 which pycharm CANNOT install:

- pyredstat==0.2.5
- orjson==3.4.6

what i get is:

```
Collecting pyreadstat==0.2.5
  Using cached pyreadstat-0.2.5.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      It seems you are using windows 32bit, you will need to find zlib1.dll and li
biconv-2.dll from mingw 32 bits, (It is usually in the bin folder of mingw32 if yo
u are using msys) put it in the folder win_libs/32bit, remove the sys.exit in the 
setup.py file and try again. Or maybe the dlls in the 64 bit folder work for 32 bi
t as well ... couldn't try as I don't have access toa 32 bit machine. Sorry!      
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with 
pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> pyreadstat
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

It already shows an hint on how to try to solve the issue but what is strange is that I DO NOT have a 32 bit architecture (My Python ver. is 3.7 32bit), but my Windows is 64 bit based, so the solution seems quite strage and i do not want to touch .dll stuff. Thank you all!

ps: i tried the installation using the pip command also.

Comment: Do you have a 32bit or 64bit version of Python installed?

Comment: Hi, on my Windows I have Python 3.7 32 bit

Comment: If not specifically required by your application I'd suggest using Python 3.7 64 bit and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Python 64 bit installed. If you have 32 bit Python, even if you have a 64 bit machine, Pyreadstat will fail as it is not possible to compile for 32 bit Python at the moment. Please install 64 bit Python, unfortunately that is the only solution.